# Laravel DomCrawler ошибка с кириллицей

Tags: php, laravel

Есть html файл вида

```html
<table width=820 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=3 border=0>
<tr align=left><td colspan=2>Символ</td><td colspan=4>GBPUSD (Great Britain Pound vs US Dollar)</td></tr>
<tr align=left><td colspan=2>Период</td><td colspan=4>1 Час (H1)  2013.01.02 09:00 - 2013.11.29 23:00    (2013.01.01 - 2013.11.30)</td></tr>
<tr align=left><td colspan=2>Модель</td><td colspan=4>Все тики (наиболее точный метод на основе всех наименьших доступных таймфреймов)</td></tr>
</table>
```

, при получении через DomCrawler к примеру текста второго tr

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$text  = $crawler->filter('table tr')->eq(1)->text();
```

то полученная строка имеет вид

```
ÐÐµÑÐ¸Ð¾Ð´1 Ð§Ð°Ñ (H1) 2013.01.02 09:00 - 2013.11.29 23:00 (2013.01.01 - 2013.11.30)
```

. И так везде где присутствует кириллица. Используется Laravel 5.3 и php 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась через добавление контента не в конструктор

```
        $crawler = new Crawler($html);
```

А через метод

```
        
        $crawler = new Crawler();
        $crawler->addHtmlContent($html);
```